# Comparing actual data to target data and displaying it in a grid

Tags: matlab

I want to compare my measurement data (consisting of coordinates) with an ideal sphere and display their deviation in a grid. So, subtract my measurement data from the sphere and represent this 'surface' as a color map. My problem is that the measurement data has a dimension of 2639x3 and does not match the sphere. Furthermore, I want to create the process in a way that it can also be used for other geometries. That's why I thought of using the grid to calculate the vertical distance from the XY points to the points.
I'm trying to do it like in the picture to visualize the deviation from my measurement data.

[image]

you can find the data.mat here : https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/2030764-comparing-actual-data-to-target-data-and-displaying-it-in-a-grid

```
clear , clc, close all
load("data.mat")
x=data(:,1);
y=data(:,2);
z=data(:,3);

%% Sphere
[sp_x, sp_y, sp_z] = sphere(100); 
sp_x = sp_x * 24.2693; 
sp_y = sp_y * 24.2693;
sp_z = sp_z * 24.2693; 
sp_x = sp_x + 0.002; 
sp_y = sp_y + 1.89e-04; 
sp_z = sp_z + 0.585;

%% Grid
grid_length = 50;  
grid_width = 50; 
spacing = 0.5;  
[grid_x, grid_y, grid_z] = meshgrid(-grid_length/2:spacing:grid_length/2, -grid_width/2:spacing:grid_width/2, 0:spacing:0);
grid_x = grid_x + 0.002; 
grid_y = grid_y + 1.89e-04;
grid_z = grid_z + 0.585;

%% Deviation 
vertical_sp = zeros(size(grid_x));
vertical_data = zeros(size(grid_x));
for i = 1:size(grid_x, 1) 
    for j = 1:size(grid_x, 2)
        dev_sp = abs(sp_z(i, j) - grid_z(i, j));
        vertical_sp(i, j) = dev_sp;
    end
end
for ii = 1:size(grid_x, 1) 
    for jj = 1:size(grid_x, 2)
        dev_data = abs(z(ii, jj) - grid_z(ii, jj));
        vertical_data(ii, jj) = dev_data;
    end
end
```

Comment: Your surface plot looks nice, but its expressivness is limited. I'd recommend you to visualize the ideal sphere (maybe transparent) and then plot your measurement points in the same figure. The colors of those points should correspond to their distance to the ideal sphere (red -> high distance, blue -> low distance).
For other geometries consider creating a dense mesh of the ideal geometry and then calculate the distance of a measurement point to the closest vertex with the nearest neighbor function (https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/triangulation.nearestneighbor.html).